# Parse Date, SimpleXML, Android

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

i use simple-xml in Android, and I get a date in the follow format `"2013-05-13+02:00"`, 
I try to get the date in String format, after that i can't parse this date in this format!

```
private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate){ 
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(inputDate);  
        Log.i("date: ", date.toString());
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        Log.i("error ParseException : ", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

i get this error :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-05-13+02:00"
```

Comment: Did u tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate){ 
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(inputDate);  
        Log.i("date: ", date.toString());
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        Log.i("error ParseException : ", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```